# In a Django view requiring two-factor authentication as well as login and permission, what should be the relative order of the mixin classes?

Tags: python, django, two-factor-authentication

I'm reviewing a class-based view which uses the [`OTPRequiredMixin`](https://django-two-factor-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/implementing.html#mixin) as well as the [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) and the [`PermissionRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-permissionrequiredmixin-mixin). I understand that the ordering of the mixins in the inheritance chain is important; for example, the docs state that the `LoginRequiredMixin` should be in the leftmost position.

My guess is that the mixins should be ordered as follows:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin
from two_factor.views.mixins import OTPRequiredMixin


class AccessMixin(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, OTPRequiredMixin):
    pass
```

I wasn't able to find any confirmation of this from the Django Two-Factor Authentication docs, however. Is this the correct way to order the mixins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need the `LoginRequiredMixin` when you use `PermissionRequiredMixin` - an anonymous user will fail the permission check and be redirected.

The order of the other two mixins probably doesn't matter. Your current ordering (`PermissionRequiredMixin` before `OTPRequiredMixin`) means that the permission will be checked first. You can switch the order if you want the `OTPRequiredMixin` check to run first.